# GIT - force side branch to copy contents from master branch(non bare)

Tags: git, github, version-control

So I have a new non-bare git repo (git init).

Then I do an initial commit(git commit -a -m "initial commit")

Now someone creates a new branch(branchEx) to perform experiments
He also made commits to it
He pushes it using (git push -u origin branchEx)

But someone else on the team committed important changes on master branch

To continue the experiment, we need to make branchEx copy exactly the contents of master branch and restart our experiment.

Note that we don't care about the commited changes of branchEx. We just want branchEx to copy exactly the master branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have

```
A -- B <--(master)
 \
  X -- Y -- Z <--(branchEx)
```

Because you don't care about the commits already on `branchEx`, what I recommend is to move the `branchEx` ref.  For example

```
git checkout master
git branch -f branchEx
```

Now in your local repo, it's just as if `branchEx` were newly created at `master`.

```
A -- B <--(master)(branchEx)
```

(Technically commits `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are still present, but they're presumably not reachable from any ref now and may eventually be garbage-collected.)

This does mean that you have to do a force push, which is *usually* something I'd avoid; the reason I would do it in this case is, it's a one-time cost.  I can conceive of ways to avoid it, but in addition to being more complicated they have costs that won't "go away" just by completing an annoying procedure.

So:

```
git checkout branchEx
git push -f
```

Now that one time cost I was talking about: from the perspective of any clones that might contain `origin/branchEx` refs, this ref has moved in an unexpected way.  If such a clone has a (local) branch that treats `origin/branchEx` as upstream (normally this would be a local branch named `branchEx`), then it will need to sync up with this unexpected move.  One way to do this is

```
git checkout branchEx
git pull -f
```

Because of this, it is important to coordinate with your team any time you consider doing a "forced" push.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `git rebase`. It updates your branch and tries to apply local commits on top of it.

Example:

```
git checkout branchEx
git rebase master
```

There may be conflicts, you need to resolve them. If there are no conflicts, you are done.

If you want to discard all your local commits, then you should do `git reset --hard`. Example:

```
git checkout branchEx
git reset --hard master
```

Comment: But I want to discard every commits made to branchEx